# how to check signalr hubconnection is online or not in android?

Tags: android, signalr, signalr-hub

I am using signalr for chat api, signalr service is starting and getting chat messages for some time but, after some time signalr hub connection is not responding and im unable to contact with signalR server. How to check if signalr hubconnection is online or not in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you invoking this method than by this instance you can get the current state of hubconnection.

```
private void startSignalR() {
        Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
        mInstance.setmHubConnection(getApplicationContext());
        mInstance.setHubProxy();
        ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(mInstance.mHubConnection.getLogger());
        signalRFuture = mInstance.mHubConnection.start(clientTransport);
        try {
            signalRFuture.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            SharedPrefUtil.clearAllSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.wrong_server), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("SimpleSignalR", e.toString());
            return;
        }

        mInstance.mHubConnection.error(new ErrorCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        // Subscribe to the connected event
        mInstance.mHubConnection.connected(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("CONNECTED");
            }
        });

        mInstance.mHubConnection.reconnected(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                System.out.println("RECONNECTED");
            }
        });
        // Subscribe to the closed event
        mInstance.mHubConnection.closed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                System.out.println("DISCONNECTED");
            }
        });

        mInstance.mHubProxy.on(SignalRConstant.CLIENT_METHOD_BROADAST_MESSAGE,
                new SubscriptionHandler2<String, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(final String msg, final Object data) {
                        if (msg != null && data != null && !data.equals("")) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
                            intent.putExtra("CAPTION", msg);
                            if(msg.equals(SignalRConstant.CAPTION_LOGINPASS))
                            {
                                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(AppConstant.DATE_FORMAT).create();
                                intent.putExtra("DATA", gson.toJson(data));
                            }else{
                                intent.putExtra("DATA", data.toString());
                            }
                            sendBroadcast(intent);
                        }
                    }
                }
                , String.class, Object.class);
    }
```